# wordpress could not create directory

Tags: php, wordpress, cmd

Good day folks,
I was trying to update my wordpress site and i have this error:

> Unpacking the update… Could not create directory. Installation Failed

After googling, i have found a solution that says:

1. Web Server Ownership

   The first level is actually to make sure that your web server has ownership over the directories:
   `chown -R www-data:www-data your-wordpress-directory`
2. Directory Permissions

   The second level is also required – you must make sure that the directory permissions are properly set:

   ```
   sudo find /var/www/wordpress/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
   sudo find /var/www/wordpress/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
   ```

Could anyone guide me how to perform those tasks?

Regards

Comment: login to your root folder using ftp client/cpanel then right click on the file u will see permission, or u google how to set file permissions

Comment: You can't run the commands above without SSH access. You can change the permissions via FTP or through a control panel (if any). If you are not sure how to do that, contact your hosting provider.